# How to show only one window in qt?

Tags: qt

I have two MainWindows with WindowModality equals to Window and I would like that the the second window is shown after the first is closed (and valid).

The problem : when I use this code, I have two windows a the same time

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    LoginWindow loginWin;
    loginWin.show();

    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add some `signal` to `LoginWindow` and emit it when user close it and its valid:

```
class LoginWindow: public QMainWindow
{
.......
signals:
    void loginReady();
.....
};
```

Then in your `main` function you can do somethisn like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ....
    LoginWindow loginWin;
    connect(&loginWin, &LoginWindow::loginReady, [](){
             MainWindow* w = new MainWindow();
             w->show();
    });
    loginWin.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

The lambda connected to `loginReady` signal will be executed when you call `emit loginReady()`.

Of course you should add `CONFIG += c++11` into your `.pro` file.